# How search by filter a data on database by textBox to show in the listview the results in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying get the data defined by the text in a `TextBox` to show in the `ListView`, but i can't find the solution to that. Can someone help me??

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCrub.png)

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far, so we can help with what's not working.

Comment: That code i'm just list the objects. I want search by filter, do u got it?

Comment: It is helpful for us to see the code, so we can see how you're storing and displaying the data, and so we have something to start with. As it is, there is no data shown anywhere, even in your screenshot.

Comment: Ready, bro. See there :)

Comment: Thanks, but it should be formatted code in your question, not a screenshot. Something people can copy and paste. But it looks like someone is already helping you, so next time, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

try using this code.

```
IEnumerable<ListViewItem> lv = listViewItems.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>();
var matchingItems = lv.Where(i => i.Text.Contains(txtBoxName.Text));
```

try this..

```
private void populate()
    {
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    SqlCommand cm;
    if(textBox1.Text == "")
       cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbName", con);
    else
        cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbName WHERE Nome='" + txtBoxName.Text + "'", con);

    try
    {

        SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            ListViewItem it = new 
            ListViewItem(dr["fillingcode"].ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(dr["ID"].ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(dr["Nome"].ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(dr["Convenio"].ToString());
            it.SubItems.Add(dr["Contato"].ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(it);

        }

        dr.Close();
        dr.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Fellow, this code not work. But perhaps can be the way to solve it. The code above return all objects of database, but i just wanna to search the object that am informating and then show in the listview.